# Inherited class vector of same type identical

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a strange problem. I am using custom class called shape with inherited shapes like sphere, cuboid, ...

All of these shapes are stored in

```
vector <Shape*> shape;
```

and everything is going along fine I can verify that the data is going in correctly. However, when a new shape is entered, all of the previously entered shapes of the same type now are identical to the newest member.

As an example:

A simple input file could be

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
1
1
0 1 1 1 1 2
0 1 0 0 0.75 1
0 1 0 0 -1.25 1
0 1 10 10 10 1
```

and after the first shape

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
1
1
0 1 1 1 1 2
```

which is identical, afterwards

```
0 0 0 1 1 1
2
1
0 1 0 0 0.75 1
0 1 0 0 0.75 1
```

and then it continues to diverge.

The file where the vector resides in ShapeContainer.cpp and ShapeContainer.H, if you think that what the problem is in another file please ask.

Thank you very much for all of your help.

Regards,

John

```
#include "ShapeContainer.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void ShapeContainer::PrintT3D (ostream & out, ShapeContainer & SC) 
{
  //    Initialize and Assign Counters  //
  unsigned int Vertex_ID = 1;
  unsigned int Curve_ID = 1;
  unsigned int Patch_ID = 1;
  unsigned int Surface_ID = 1;
  unsigned int Shell_ID = 1;
  unsigned int Region_ID = 1;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SC.shape.size(); i++)
    {
            out << "## Shape " << i + 1 << ": " << SC.shape[i]->get_shape_name() << endl;
      SC.shape[i]->prepare_t3d_input(Vertex_ID, Curve_ID, Patch_ID, Surface_ID, Shell_ID, Region_ID, 0);
      out << *SC.shape[i];
    }
}

void ShapeContainer::PrintStat3D (ostream & out, ShapeContainer & SC)
{
  vector <double> LocalCoords;
  vector <double> LocalProps;

  //    Start printing updated Stat3D file //
  out << SC.BoundingBoxDimensions << endl;
  out << SC.shape.size() << endl;
  out << SC.NumberModes(SC) << endl;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SC.shape.size(); i++)
    {
      LocalCoords = SC.shape[i]->get_coords();
      LocalProps  = SC.shape[i]->get_properties();

      out << SC.shape[i]->get_shape_type() << " " << SC.shape[i]->get_mode() << " " << LocalCoords << " " << LocalProps << endl;
    }
}

void ShapeContainer::ThrowOut(ShapeContainer & SC)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SC.shape.size(); i++)
    {
            if ((SC.shape[i]->InBoundingBox(SC.BoundingBoxDimensions))==false) {
                SC.shape.erase(SC.shape.begin()+i-1);
                i=i-1;
        }
    }
}

unsigned int ShapeContainer::NumberModes (ShapeContainer & SC)
{
  vector <int> ModesList;
  ModesList.resize(SC.shape.size(),0);

  for (unsigned int i=0;i<ModesList.size();i++) {ModesList[i]=SC.shape[i]->get_mode();}

  sort (ModesList.begin(), ModesList.end());

  unsigned int count=1;
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<ModesList.size()-1;i++)
    {
      if(ModesList[i]!=ModesList[i+1])
    count++;
    }    
  return count;
}
```

ShapeContainer.H

```
#ifndef _SHAPECONTAINER_H_
#define _SHAPECONTAINER_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "utils.H"

#include "Shape.H"
#include "Sphere.H"
#include "Cuboid.H"
#include "Ellipsoid.H"
#include "Octahedron.H"

using namespace std;

class ShapeContainer
{
public:
    ShapeContainer(){};
    ~ShapeContainer(){};

    void initialize();

/// Friend of Print Functions ///
void PrintT3D (ostream & out, ShapeContainer & SC);
void PrintStat3D (ostream & out, ShapeContainer & SC);

void ThrowOut(ShapeContainer & SC);

/// Private access functions ///
    void set_BoundingBox(vector <double> BB) {BoundingBoxDimensions = BB;};   // Cooresponds to box at (x,y,z) with dims (dx,dy,dz)
    unsigned int NumberModes (ShapeContainer & SC);

/// Vector-Like Functions ///
    void push_back(Shape* NewShape) {shape.push_back(NewShape);}

private:
vector <double> BoundingBoxDimensions;
vector <Shape*> shape;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Is it me or this question is just not understandable ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: It's not just you.

Comment: This "question" is in fact a request for personal debugging help.

Comment: I'm bugging just before the breakpoint, "and after the first shape" :-)

Comment: @StephaneRolland - it isn't even a question. I see no question mark ("?") anywhere in this post.

Answer (score 1):

A typical case when you have two pointers that seem to point to the same data is because the actually *do* point to the same data. This is often the case when you have a variable and uses the address-of operator to push a pointer to that variable into a collection.

An example:

```
struct Foo
{
    // Lost of fields
};

int main()
{
    Foo myFoo;
    std::vector<Foo*> allFoo;

    while (std::getline(cin, input))
    {
        myFoo.field1 = parseFirstValueFromString(input);
        myFoo.field2 = parseSecondValueFromString(input);

        allFoo.push_back(&myFoo);
    }
}
```

What happens in the above example is that the first time you push a pointer to `myFoo` into the vector, but the second time through the loop you modify that same object, and pushing the exact same pointer.

What you need to solve the problem above is create a completely *new* object instance in the loop. This is done using pointers and the `new` operator, as so:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo*> allFoo;

    while (std::getline(cin, input))
    {
        Foo* myFoo = new Foo;

        myFoo->field1 = parseFirstValueFromString(input);
        myFoo->field2 = parseSecondValueFromString(input);

        allFoo.push_back(myFoo);
    }
}
```

In the code above, a unique instance will be created each iteration in the loop.

Comment: I think that this is the issue, I tried to add


    if (shape_type == 0) {Shape* sphere = new Sphere;}

    else if (shape_type == 2) {Shape* ellipsoid = new Ellipsoid;}

    else if (shape_type == 3) {Shape* cuboid = new Cuboid;}

    else if (shape_type == 4) {Shape* octahedron = new Octahedron;}


but I am getting the compiling error that none of these are declared in the scope.

Comment: @user1543042 Declare a generic `Shape* shape = 0;` _before_ the if-statements, and then do e.g. `shape = new Cuboid` etc. in them. Then after the statements add a check for non-zero `shape` and add that shape.